# I can`t boot Ubuntu 18.04 lts without USB flash drive

Tags: boot

I have Lenovo x1 carbon gen 5th. Friend of mine convinced me to get this laptop because it is certify by Ubuntu. However, I cannot start Ubuntu without USB flash drive. Is there anyone with any idea what happened?

Comment: Maybe you need to install Ubuntu on the hard drive using the USB flash drive which has Ubuntu on it. Just a thought.

Comment: Do you really just want to know what happened? (Most likely an erroneous selection during install). Or do you actually want to know how to fix it?

Comment: I want to fix it. Cause I already met with the suggestion of switching to different linux. But I really like Ubunu